# React: Update one state variable using another state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component, react-state

What I am trying to achieve:

Retrieve `book`-> take `book.chapterIds[0]` to update `currentChapter` -> take `currentChapter` to update `chapters`

I am using one state variable(Book) to set another state variable(chapters), like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getBook(match.params.id);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, []);

useEffect(() => {
 setCurrentChapter(book.chapterIds[0]);
 // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [book]);

useEffect(() => {
  getChapter(currentChapter);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, [currentChapter]);
```

For second useEffect, I end up getting: `Uncaught TypeError: book.chapterIds is undefined`

Here is what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (Object.keys(book).length !== 0) {
 setCurrentChapter(book.chapterIds[0]);
}
 // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [book]);
```

which kinda works, but I still ends up triggering:

```
useEffect(() => {
 getChapter(currentChapter);
 // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [currentChapter]);
```

where both book and currentChapter is undefined

App.js

```
const [book, setBook] = useState({});
const [chapters, setChapters] = useState({});
const [currentChapter, setCurrentChapter] = useState();   
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const getBook = async (id) => {
 setLoading(true);
 const res = await axios.get(`<someurl><with id>`);
 console.log(res.data);
 setBook(res.data.book);
 setLoading(false);
};

const getChapter = async (chapterId) => {
  if (chapters[chapterId] === undefined) {
    console.log(`<someurl><with id & chapterId>`);
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await axios.get(
     `<someurl><with id & chapterId>`
    );
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(res.data);
    setChapters({
     ...chapters,
     [chapterId]: res.data.chapter,
   });
  }
 };
```

Book.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
  getBook(match.params.id);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (Object.keys(book).length !== 0) {
   setCurrentChapter(book.chapterIds[0]);
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [book]);

 useEffect(() => {
  getChapter(currentChapter);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, [currentChapter]);
```

Also, I get `book.chapterIds` as undefined on using it inside Book component`return()`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set all initial states as null:

```
const [book, setBook] = useState(null);
const [chapters, setChapters] = useState(null);
const [currentChapter, setCurrentChapter] = useState(null);
```

Then your useEffects:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  getBook(match.params.id);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, []);

useEffect(() => {
 if(book && book.chapterIds?.length > 0)
     setCurrentChapter(book.chapterIds[0]);
 // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [book]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(currentChapter)
    getChapter(currentChapter);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, [currentChapter]);
```

Comment: Setting all my states to null, threw error. But on updating useEffect per your suggestions did resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Care to share the error you've got when setting the useState to null?

Comment: Also, please mark as correct answer if that solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I get: "Uncaught TypeError: book is null" for line: const { title, author, chapterIds } = book;

Comment: You might need to refactor your code. 
Something like:
const { title, author, chapterIds } = book ?? {};

Should do the trick.